# Build Playframework 2.3.5 from source

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I'm a newbie to Playframework and building from source as well. Due to the restrictions in our network, i cannot download any zip files, hence took the source of playframework from git and followed the instructions in [a link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.5/BuildingFromSource).

Was able to run the **build** and the **publish-local** commands and got the jars installed under the local directory of the repository.

But after this, i'm not sure how to proceed. I do not see any activator launch or similar jars in the repository. Can we run the play applications without an activator ? I've searched over the net, but all the links point me to the activator. Again, activator is downloaded as zip and hence restricted for me.

It would be great, if you could guide me how to proceed from here.

Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S : Have run the **test** and **runtests** commands as well. Just in case if needed.

Comment: You don't need to use the activator to run Play 2.3.5. You can just use sbt. You might have to clone that from github as well, build and install it, and then you just just run "sbt" inside your play project.

Comment: Yes, i was trying that in parallel. Was able to run the sample play applications. But creating a new application is not that easy and simple as it is with Play 1.2.7. I will try to give the steps i have followed, just if someone else hit the same road like me.  @rspencer - Thanks for your inputs.